# Lua exiting immediately after throwing an error

Tags: lua

I'm using the Lua 5.2.3 Binary for windows, and I'm trying to run a code. I know the code is throwing an error, but the interpreter closes immediately, so I can't find out what it is.

Is there a way to stop it from closing immediately?

**Edit: All my lua scripts pretty much exit immediately after the program ends. Is there a way to stop this too?**

Comment: Run lua from a command prompt instead of double-clicking the lua file?

Comment: Many options here, Etan's suggestion is the most straight-forward. You can also set your windows registry to execute lua files with `lua -i %1` and you'll enter the interpreter after running the script. You can also wrap your script in a pcall and run `os.execute "pause"` at the end.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using command prompt? Also its a separate interpreter, not the one that runs with command prompt

Answer (score 1):

In Lua scripts, you can catch exceptions and handle them using the function pcall().
You should have a look at [8 – Compilation, Execution, and Errors](http://www.lua.org/pil/8.html) and espacially [8.4 – Error Handling and Exceptions](http://www.lua.org/pil/8.4.html).